# Python pandas dataframe from csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have some data in a csv in the following format:

```
5494;2006;4  
3579;1143;3   
1251;2567;2   
5687;652;4   
3018;3440;4  
...
```

When I do

```
df = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv')
```

, I only get 1 column 5494;2006;4 and the values below it are 3579;1143;3 ... What I would like to do instead is make 3 columns, each one representing values separated by ";" in the csv. Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks :)

Comment: use sep=';'...https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define the seperater, `df = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv', sep=';')`